# jquery append () no funciona el metodo Calcular sobre elementos agregados dinámicamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
                    $(function () {
                    var scntDiv = $('#dynamicDiv');
                    var i=2;
                      $(document).on('click', '#addInput', function () {
                        $('<table class="grupo">'+
                            '<tr>'+
                                '<td><input  type="text"  name="componente[]" id="componente" value="" placeholder="Componente" /></td>'+
                                '<td><input type="text" name="nparte[]" id="nparte"  placeholder="N Parte"   /></td>'+
                                '<td><input  title="SOLO NUMEROS" name="cantidad[]" type="text" value="0"  id="cantidad"  placeholder="Cantidad" pattern="[0-9]+" onkeypress="ValidaSoloNumeros()" /></td>'+
                                '<td><input  title="SOLO NUMEROS"  type="text"  name="precio[]"  value="0"  id="precio"  placeholder="Precio"  onkeypress="ValidaSoloNumeros()" /> </td>'+
                                '<td><input  type="text"  value="0"  name="total[]" id="total"  placeholder="total"  readonly /></td>'+
                                '<td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" id="remInput">'+
                                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>'+
                                '<i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></td>'+
                            '</tr>'+
                        '</table>').appendTo("#dynamicDiv");
                        i++;    
                          return false; 
                      });
                      $(document).on('click', '#remInput', function () {
                          $(this).parents('p').remove();
                          return false;
                      });
                  });
```

(1)Al hacer append. se crean los elementos dinámicamente en el html , pero cuando se generan, la función de cálculo no los reconoce..

```
            <table class="grupo">
                <tr>
                    <td><input  type="text"  name="componente[]" id="componente" value="" placeholder="Componente" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nparte[]" id="nparte"  placeholder="N Parte"   /></td>
                    <td><input  title="SOLO NUMEROS" name="cantidad[]" type="text" value="0"  id="cantidad"  placeholder="Cantidad" pattern="[0-9]+" onkeypress="ValidaSoloNumeros()" /></td>
                    <td><input  title="SOLO NUMEROS"  type="text"  name="precio[]"  value="0"  id="precio"  placeholder="Precio"  onkeypress="ValidaSoloNumeros()" /> </td>
                    <td><input  type="text"  value="0"  name="total[]" id="total"  placeholder="total"  readonly /></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" id="remInput">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

(2)Estos elementos html si son reconocidos por la función de cálcular js

```
     $(document).ready(function()
      {
      $(".grupo").keyup(function()
    {
    var cantidad=$(this).find("input[name^=cantidad").val();    
    var precio=$(this).find("input[name^=precio").val();
    var tot=0;
    tot = parseFloat(precio)*parseFloat(cantidad);
    $(this).find("input[name^=total").val(tot.toFixed(2));
    $(this).find(" 
    [class=total]").html(parseFloat(precio)*parseFloat(cantidad)); 
    var total=0;
    var igv = 0;
    var completo=0;

          $(".grupo .total").each(function()
        {
          total=total+parseFloat($(this).html());
          igv = total * 0.18;
          completo = igv + total;


        })
        $(".total .total ").html(total).val();
        $("input[name=subtotal").val(total.toFixed(2));
        $("input[name=igv").val(igv.toFixed(2));
        $("input[name=completo").val(completo.toFixed(2));


      });
  });
```

(3)calcular js

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta, estas en es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Si, gracias, ya lo cambie, ojala me puedan ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que los elementos dinamicos no estan presentes cuando cargas la pagina.  Para que funcione correctamente debes usar `on()` asi:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $(document).on("keyup", ".grupo", function()
{
var cantidad=$(this).find("input[name^=cantidad").val();    
var precio=$(this).find("input[name^=precio").val();
var tot=0;
tot = parseFloat(precio)*parseFloat(cantidad);
$(this).find("input[name^=total").val(tot.toFixed(2));
$(this).find(" 
[class=total]").html(parseFloat(precio)*parseFloat(cantidad)); 
var total=0;
var igv = 0;
var completo=0;

      $(".grupo .total").each(function()
    {
      total=total+parseFloat($(this).html());
      igv = total * 0.18;
      completo = igv + total;


    })
    $(".total .total ").html(total).val();
    $("input[name=subtotal").val(total.toFixed(2));
    $("input[name=igv").val(igv.toFixed(2));
    $("input[name=completo").val(completo.toFixed(2));


  });
});
```

Comment: Ya lo solucione, como tal y como los describiste.  solo me hacia falta el .on  " $(document).on("keyup", ".grupo", function()". Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

tu error es que le estas enviado un evento `onclick="javascript:void(0)"` que no es mas que decirle no hagas nada!
tambien estas ejecutando una funcion `onkeypress="ValidaSoloNumeros()` pero tambien tienes un listener `jquery` para el keyup
debes decidirte por una o por otra! y utilizar [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) que seria `$(document).on("keyup",".grupo",function()` para que pueda leer los elementos dinamicos!

> **Nota:** utiliza los [templates de javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para eso estan ya no es necesario concatenar y concatenar

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#addInput', function () {
    let template = `<table class="grupo">
    <tr>
        <td><input  type="text"  name="componente[]" id="componente" value="" placeholder="Componente" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nparte[]" id="nparte"  placeholder="N Parte"/></td>
        <td><input  title="SOLO NUMEROS" name="cantidad[]" type="text" value="0"  id="cantidad"  placeholder="Cantidad" pattern="[0-9]+" onkeypress="ValidaSoloNumeros()"/></td>
        <td><input  title="SOLO NUMEROS"  type="text"  name="precio[]"  value="0"  id="precio"  placeholder="Precio"  onkeypress="ValidaSoloNumeros()" /> </td>
        <td><input  type="text"  value="0"  name="total[]" id="total"  placeholder="total"  readonly /></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-danger"  id="remInput">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></td>
    </tr></table>`;

    $("#dynamicDiv").append(template);  
        return false; 
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#remInput', function (e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Bryro por tu tiempo, tambien me ayudo.